# Present simple and present continuous difference

Tags: difference, present-tense, present-continuous, present-simple

What is the difference between this two sentences: "**He doesn't listen to me**" and "**He isn't listening to me**"? Do they mean different things? What tense in what case should i use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the usual difference between the present and present continuous.

"He doesn't listen" = always,  a general fact = "He never listens"

"He isn't listening" = right now.  Temporary fact. "He sometimes listens, but not now."